# How to add lines to 3D?

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

[image: 3D_Image]

I rendered a 3D human model using three.js and I was wondering how to add angle lines like the one I painted on the 3D image in red colored line.

Comment: you can look into EllipseCurve

Comment: Or if you want a 3D line, check out `QuadraticBezierCurve3`
http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Extras.Curves/QuadraticBezierCurve3

Comment: @Pimskie Thanks! this is what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

It looks in your example like if you simply want to paint 2D lines on top of the 3D canvas. If that is indeed what you want then you could also simply use a 2D canvas to do this. It will be much easier to implement.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a line in a 3D space you can use

```
THREE.EllipseCurve:

var curve = new THREE.EllipseCurve(
    0,  0,            // ax, aY
    10, 10,           // xRadius, yRadius
    0,  2 * Math.PI,  // aStartAngle, aEndAngle
    false,            // aClockwise
    0                 // aRotation 
);

var path = new THREE.Path( curve.getPoints( 50 ) );
var geometry = path.createPointsGeometry( 50 );
var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial( { color : 0xff0000 } );

// Create the final Object3d to add to the scene
var ellipse = new THREE.Line( geometry, material );
```

source [here](http://threejs.org/docs/index.html#Reference/Extras.Curves/EllipseCurve)